# How to set app to default to language based on region it was first activated

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want set the app to default to language based on region it was first activated

Comment: Have you searched in the documentation? [CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture?view=net-5.0). (Your question is not quite clear).

Comment: I need to know language based on region

Comment: not the language currently selected by user in phone os (either Android or iOS)?

Comment: No,  I want to set app default language based on region it was first activated

Answer (score 1):

[Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/localization/#specifying-default-and-supported-languages-in-infoplist) in iOS:

> In Technical Q&A QA1828: How iOS Determines the Language For Your App,
> Apple describes how iOS selects a language to use in an app. The
> following factors impact which language is displayed:

- The user's preferred languages (found in the `Settings` app)
- The `localizations` bundled with the app (.lproj folders)
- `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` (Info.plist value specifying the default
  language for the app)
- `CFBundleLocalizations` (Info.plist array specifying all supported
  localizations)

As indicated in the Technical Q&A, `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` represents an app's default region and language. If the app doesn't explicitly support any of a user's preferred languages, it will use the language specified by this field.

[Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/localization) in Android:

Users choose their language in `Settings > Language & input`. This selection controls both the language displayed and regional settings used (eg. for date and number formatting).

The current locale can be queried via the current context's Resources:

```
var lang = Resources.Configuration.Locale; // eg. "es_ES"
```

In both iOS and Android, you should add `localized strings`, `images`, and `other resources` with different language in your project. Then when your app start, the app will choose the corresponding language if you have in your project, otherwise it will use the default language.